# Force include all classes in a folder in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, include, models

I can force include one model by:

```
Yii::import("application.models.modelName", true);
```

What should I do to include all models from the models directory?

Here's what I've tried:

```
Yii::import("application.models.*", true);
```

It doesn't work because Yii will import only when there is a need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Really, why would you want to import it except to use them?

Autoloading php feature is priceless :)

Answer (score 0):

Yii can't do that. Importing is pretty lightweight compared to real inclusion, but if you must accomplish that, here's a snippet:

```
foreach(glob(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.models').'/*.php') as $script) {
   require $script;
}
```

I don't doubt there are cases when this approach is the best, but you really have to make sure it is in your scenario.